# Use Regular expressions extract specific characters

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

```
text <- c('d__Viruses|f__Closteroviridae|g__Closterovirus|s__Citrus_tristeza_virus',
'd__Viruses|o__Tymovirales|f__Alphaflexiviridae|g__Mandarivirus|s__Citrus_yellow_vein_clearing_virus',
'd__Viruses|o__Ortervirales|f__Retroviridae|s__Columba_palumbus_retrovirus')
```

I have tried but failed:

```
str_extract(text, pattern = 'f.*\\|')
```

How can I get

`f__Closteroviridae`

`f__Alphaflexiviridae`

`f__Retroviridae`

Any help will be high appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the regex non-greedy and since you don't want `"|"` in final output use positive lookahead.

```
stringr::str_extract(text, 'f.*?(?=\\|)') 
#[1] "f__Closteroviridae"   "f__Alphaflexiviridae" "f__Retroviridae"
```

---

In base R, we can use `sub` :

```
sub('.*(f_.*?)\\|.*', '\\1', text)
#[1] "f__Closteroviridae"   "f__Alphaflexiviridae" "f__Retroviridae"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a base R solution, I would use `regmatches` along with `gregexpr`:

```
m <- gregexpr("\\bf__[^|]+", text)
as.character(regmatches(text, m))

[1] "f__Closteroviridae"   "f__Alphaflexiviridae" "f__Retroviridae"
```

The advantage of using `gregexpr` as above is that should an input contain *more* than one `f__` matching term, we could also capture it.  For example:

```
x <- 'd__Viruses|f__Closteroviridae|g__Closterovirus|f__some_virus'
m <- gregexpr("\\bf__[^|]+", x)
regmatches(x, m)[[1]]

[1] "f__Closteroviridae" "f__some_virus"
```

**Data:**

```
text <- c('d__Viruses|f__Closteroviridae|g__Closterovirus|s__Citrus_tristeza_virus',
          'd__Viruses|o__Tymovirales|f__Alphaflexiviridae|g__Mandarivirus|s__Citrus_yellow_vein_clearing_virus',
          'd__Viruses|o__Ortervirales|f__Retroviridae|s__Columba_palumbus_retrovirus')
```

Comment: Tim, can word boundary (\b) be also used for special characters such as "|" ? Could you please explain what [^|] does. I know "^" is used to start of  a line, but couldn't understand the construct [^|].

Comment: @KarthikS A word boundary `\b`, by definition, is the interface between a word character, such as a letter, and a non word character, such as pipe `|`.  You might want to review a good regex tutorial.